# No implicit for Append.Value[...] found with Def.task to generate files in SBT 0.13?

Tags: sbt

I'm having an issue migrating my project to SBT `0.13`.

For some reason, the snippet from [Generate sources](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Howto/generatefiles.html#sources) from the SBT documentation doesn't work for me.

Neither a simple `.sbt` build definition nor a Scala build definition work, unfortunately. Project definition is taken from the documentation:

```
name := "sbt-test"

sourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task {
  val file = (sourceManaged in Compile).value / "demo" / "Test.scala"
  IO.write(file, """object Test extends App { println("Hi") }""")
  Seq(file)
}
```

The compiler complains about the type error when compiling the project definition:

```
~/P/sbt-test ▶ sbt
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/phearnot/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/phearnot/Projects/sbt-test/project
/Users/phearnot/Projects/sbt-test/build.sbt:3: error: No implicit for Append.Value[Seq[sbt.Task[Seq[java.io.File]]], sbt.std.FullInstance.M[Seq[java.io.File]]] found,
  so sbt.std.FullInstance.M[Seq[java.io.File]] cannot be appended to Seq[sbt.Task[Seq[java.io.File]]]
sourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task {
                            ^
[error] Type error in expression
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

**UPDATE:** Now that [AlexIv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1078381/alexiv) has pointed out the problem in my SBT file definition, I wonder what is the proper way to move it into a Scala build definition?

Comment: Re "I wonder what is the proper way to move it into a scala build definition?" - I'm also struggling to achieve this.

Answer (score 8):

Change `Def.task` in your build.sbt (from gist) to `Def.task[Seq[File]]` or just leave `task[Seq[File]]` cause `Def` is automatically imported into `build.sbt`:

```
name := "sbt-test"

sourceGenerators in Compile += task[Seq[File]] {
  val file = (sourceManaged in Compile).value / "demo" / "Test.scala"
  IO.write(file, """object Test extends App { println("Hi") }""")
  Seq(file)
}
```

Then call `compile` in sbt. `Test.scala` will be generated in `./target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/demo/Test.scala`

Comment: That really did the trick, thanks! So the the problem is scala compiler couldn't infer proper type for task definition?

Comment: @SergeyNazarov i believe so. Task is defined with a macro, i'm good at them, but i believe that it's because of the implementation and has nothing to do with scalac. So in this case you have to provide explicit result type

Answer (score 0):

Use `<+=` instead of `+=`:

```
name := "sbt-test"

sourceGenerators in Compile <+= Def.task {
  val file = (sourceManaged in Compile).value / "demo" / "Test.scala"
  IO.write(file, """object Test extends App { println("Hi") }""")
  Seq(file)
}
```

Comment: The `<+=` syntax is deprecated in 0.13.13. http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/sbt-0.13-Tech-Previews.html

Answer (score 0):

My sbt version is 0.13.8 and it works for me.