# How to fix a variety of "No implicit for Append.Value[...]" errors when upgrading to SBT 1.x.x from 0.13.x?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm using SBT 1.2.8 after migrating from 0.13.7; the old variants used e.g. `<+=` instead of `+=`, in e.g. `unmanagedClasspath in Compile += baseDirectory map { bd => Attributed.blank(bd / ".." / "config") },` but such operators have been removed.

I've seen a few other related questions, but the types involved seem significantly different enough to be unhelpful to me:

1. [No implicit for Append.Value[...] found with Def.task to generate files in SBT 0.13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954315/no-implicit-for-append-value-found-with-def-task-to-generate-files-in-sbt-0)
2. [sbt: No implicit for Append.Value[Seq[java.io.File], sbt.Def.Initialize[java.io.File]] found,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54900891/sbt-no-implicit-for-append-valueseqjava-io-file-sbt-def-initializejava-io))

The three relevant consecutive lines in my file are:

```
  unmanagedClasspath in Compile += baseDirectory map { bd => Attributed.blank(bd / ".." / "config") },
  unmanagedClasspath in Runtime ++= (unmanagedClasspath in Compile),
  unmanagedClasspath in Test ++= (unmanagedClasspath in Compile),
```

This generates the following errors:

```
build.sbt:70: error: No implicit for Append.Value[sbt.Keys.Classpath, sbt.Def.Initialize[sbt.Task[sbt.internal.util.Attributed[java.io.File]]]] found,
  so sbt.Def.Initialize[sbt.Task[sbt.internal.util.Attributed[java.io.File]]] cannot be appended to sbt.Keys.Classpath
  unmanagedClasspath in Compile += baseDirectory map { bd => Attributed.blank(bd / ".." / "config") },
                                ^
build.sbt:71: error: No implicit for Append.Values[sbt.Keys.Classpath, sbt.TaskKey[sbt.Keys.Classpath]] found,
  so sbt.TaskKey[sbt.Keys.Classpath] cannot be appended to sbt.Keys.Classpath
  unmanagedClasspath in Runtime ++= (unmanagedClasspath in Compile),
                                ^
build.sbt:72: error: No implicit for Append.Values[sbt.Keys.Classpath, sbt.TaskKey[sbt.Keys.Classpath]] found,
  so sbt.TaskKey[sbt.Keys.Classpath] cannot be appended to sbt.Keys.Classpath
  unmanagedClasspath in Test ++= (unmanagedClasspath in Compile),
```

If that isn't enough information, here's the [full build.sbt](https://gist.github.com/bbarker/91deee614bc64f39ba13805c868500a5), and will be happy to inline relevant bits later.

Comment: OK, I lied; one of the references above did help me simplify the first line and appears to compile now as: `unmanagedClasspath in Compile += baseDirectory.value / ".." / "config"`

Comment: And turns out after squinting a bit, the other two lines were fixed like this: `unmanagedClasspath in Runtime ++= (unmanagedClasspath in Compile).value`

Answer (score 0):

After squinting a bit, I was able to resolve the issue after all, with the following changes. The key in each case was to recognize where to access the `.value` in question.

```
  unmanagedClasspath in Compile += baseDirectory.value / ".." / "config",
  unmanagedClasspath in Runtime ++= (unmanagedClasspath in Compile).value,
  unmanagedClasspath in Test ++= (unmanagedClasspath in Compile).value,
```

In addition to the above links, the following documentation seemed to be helpful:
-  https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Tasks.html